# How can i plot an FFT in R? (Since there's also imaginary values) I have no background in Signal Processing

Tags: r, plot, signal-processing, fft

So I have a sample data that I need to do FFT to it and then plot the result. I have searched for how to plot FFT in R but I didn't find anything. note that there are also imaginary values so how do I deal with them? I have no background in signal processing since I'm only required to do the programming part

The sample data is very large, it is a string of values separated by a '#' 
I won't add the data sample since it's very large and will fill the page> So here's the rest of the code.

```
a<-strsplit(string, '#')
b <- as.numeric(unlist(a))
x<-fft(b)
library(tcltk)
windows()
t <- 1:length(x) # 1 second sample
plot(t, x, type = "l")
#lines(t, col = "red") 
prompt  <- "hit spacebar to close plots"
extra   <- "some extra comment"
capture <- tk_messageBox(message = prompt, detail = extra)
```

Comment: Could you please familiarize yourself with the concept of a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Usually you will plot two graphs: absolute value (or power), and phase; a complex value can always be expressed as (absolute value; phase).

Comment: The relevant functions are abs and Arg (argument=angle=phase)

Comment: Here is a very nice link that provides many examples and plots of fft() in R: http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html